# Web API cant find apicontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build a small application, a api to get data with entity framework and pas out to json with web api but get the error: **{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:61267/api/GetCarousel'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'GetCarousel'."}**

Call link: http://localhost:61267/api/GetCarousel

I have learn when goggled that it seem to be many solutions to this but non seems to fit mine.

**WebApiConfig file**

```
  public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "DefaultApi",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }  

                        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}
```

**GetCarousel.cs Controller file**

This is generated from database with help of Entity Framework

```
namespace MustWebAPI.Controller
{
public class GetCarousel : ApiController
{
    private MustTestEntitie db = new MustTestEntitie();

    // GET: api/GetCarousel
    public IQueryable<GetCarousel_Result> GetGetCarousel_Result()
    {
        return db.GetCarousel_Result;
    }

    // GET: api/GetCarousel/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(GetCarousel_Result))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetGetCarousel_Result(int id)
    {
        GetCarousel_Result getCarousel_Result = db.GetCarousel_Result.Find(id);
        if (getCarousel_Result == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(getCarousel_Result);
    }

    // PUT: api/GetCarousel/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutGetCarousel_Result(int id, GetCarousel_Result getCarousel_Result)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != getCarousel_Result.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(getCarousel_Result).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!GetCarousel_ResultExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/GetCarousel
    [ResponseType(typeof(GetCarousel_Result))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostGetCarousel_Result(GetCarousel_Result getCarousel_Result)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.GetCarousel_Result.Add(getCarousel_Result);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = getCarousel_Result.Id }, getCarousel_Result);
    }

    // DELETE: api/GetCarousel/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(GetCarousel_Result))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteGetCarousel_Result(int id)
    {
        GetCarousel_Result getCarousel_Result = db.GetCarousel_Result.Find(id);
        if (getCarousel_Result == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.GetCarousel_Result.Remove(getCarousel_Result);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(getCarousel_Result);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool GetCarousel_ResultExists(int id)
    {
        return db.GetCarousel_Result.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is `GetCarousel` something specific? Because that looks like a method name to me and makes for a bad class name, hence "GetGetCarousel". Underscores in class names -- `GetCarousel_Result` -- violate [Microsoft's naming rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rename the class from `GetCarousel` to `GetCarouselController` as this is the convention for web api routing.

*As a side note, it may also be preferable to rename it to something more appropriate such as "CarouselController", typically "GetCarousel" is much more appropriate as the name of an action, not a controller.*

Comment: More specifically, he needs to rename the class `GetCarousel` to `GetCarouselController`, the name of the file is irrelevant

Comment: Agreed... subtle but relevant. Edited.

Comment: Deleted and recreated it to:

`public class CarouselController : ApiController{}`

Still get the message


`{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:61267/api/CarouselController'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'CarouselController'."}`

Comment: The url would be... http://localhost:61267/api/Carousel ... You also need to rename your actions to follow convention...